# Differents classes to every bootstrap 4 modal-backdrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

How I can set different classes to differents modal-backdrop?

I'm working with standard Bootstrap 4 modals, but the things I can found in internet doesn't work for me.

**EDIT:** I have various modals, so I need they have differentes backdrops.
For example: First modal need to have a background this css

```
background-image: url(../img/background.jpg); 
opacity: 1 !important;
```

And the others the default styles.

So, the way I'm trying to use is set a different class to the first using jQuery, but I can't get this.

**EDIT-2:** Achieved using this example! https://jsfiddle.net/a24pm8o6/1/

Comment: either i didnt get the question right or its not enough to elaborate the question please explain it more